# How to connect databases correctly in SQLAlchemy. Getting NameError: name "User" is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a many to many relationship with SQLAlchemy and flask. I think I have make all imports correctly, but for some reason I get error "NameError: name 'User' is not defined".

I read the SQLAlchemy documentation and tried their association object example. Below is my own files. Every db model is under application in it's own folder, example models.py (Picture) in application/pictures folder.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from application import db
from application.Base import Base


class Picture(Base):

    __tablename__ = "picture"

    #some code

    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("account.id"), nullable=False)

    likers = relationship("Likes", back_populates="likes")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.path = name
```

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from application import db
from application import Base


class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = "account"

    #some code

    likes = relationship("Likes", back_populates="likers")

    def __init__(self, name, username, password):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    #code associated to login
```

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

from application import db
from application import Base

class Likes(Base):

    __tablename__ = "like"  

    #some code

    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.id'),
                           nullable=False)
    picture_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('picture.id'),
                           nullable=False)


    likers = relationship(User, back_populates="likes")
    likes = relationship(Picture, back_populates="likers")


    def __init__(self, account_id, picture_id):
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.picture_id = picture_id
```

```py
#I have also imported the like db to __init__.py file before db.create_all()


from application.likes import models
```

I excepted the databases to be correctly connected, but I get an error message

likers = relationship(User.id, back_populates="likes")
NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Comment: You might want to put the models into one file and make sure they are in the right order, that the depending models are below their dependency. Alternatively you can import them where needed but that might lead to circular imports quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose your models name in ` or " when your models insertion is unordered. Example:

```
likers = relationship('User', back_populates="likes")
likes = relationship('Picture', back_populates="likers")
```

From docs (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html):

> When using the Declarative extension, the Declarative initializer allows string arguments to be passed to relationship(). These string arguments are converted into callables that evaluate the string as Python code, using the Declarative class-registry as a namespace. This allows the lookup of related classes to be automatic via their string name, and removes the need for related classes to be imported into the local module space before the dependent classes have been declared. It is still required that the modules in which these related classes appear are imported anywhere in the application at some point before the related mappings are actually used, else a lookup error will be raised when the relationship() attempts to resolve the string reference to the related class.